# angularjs scope.$watch old value is always same as new value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-watch

**Problem in short** - $scope.$watch inside an angularjs controller is always getting newValue and oldValues as same.

**Details :**

I am writing an angularjs app with three use-cases : createProduct, updateProduct and searchProducts. I am trying to have the same controller and partial for both createProduct and updateProduct. If the user navigates to '/createProduct' , logic for creating product will execute. If the user clicks on Update button on the search products page, he should see the same view with details of the selected product. Right now I am just trying to test it with dummy product data.

To achieve this, I have created a service to share the product information from SearchProduct controller to CreateProduct controller.

```
.factory('ShareProductService', function() {
        var product = {};
        var shareProductService = {};

        shareProductService.setProduct = function( _product ) {
            product = _product;
        };

        shareProductService.getProduct = function() {
            return product;
        };

        shareProductService.getProductCode = function() {
            return product.productCode;
        };

        return shareProductService;
    });
```

I am using angular-ui-router for routing. Following are route configs :

```
 $stateProvider.state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'search-products.html',
                    controller: 'SearchProductsController'
                }).state('createProduct', {
                    url: '/createProduct',
                    templateUrl: 'create-product.html',
                    controller: 'CreateProductController'
                });
            }]);
```

In search-products.html view, when user clicks on Update button he should be redirected to create-product.html view but update-specific logic should execute in the CreateProduct controller:

```
//In search-products view
<button type="button" ng-click="updateProduct()">Update Product</button>

//In search-products controller
$scope.updateProduct(productCode) = function() {
   var product = {productCode: "test"}; // Hard-coded just for for testing
   ShareProductService.setProduct(product);
   $state.go('createProduct');
}
```

Inside CreateProductController I am using a watch on ShareProductService.getProductCode to determine if it is for create or update:

```
$scope.$watch(ShareProductService.getProductCode, function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(newValue + " " + oldValue); //always same
    if(newValue !== oldValue){
        var productForEdit = ShareProductService.getProduct();
        //Update specific logic
   }else{
        //Create specific logic  
    }
});
```

The problem is that, every time the watch expression gets executed, the newValue and oldValue are always the same. I might be implementing this scenario in a non-optimal way but I am confused by the behavior of the watch. As far as I understand newValue and oldValue should be different each time the productCode is set. Is there a gap in my understanding of how watches work ?
Also, what is a better way to implement this scenario ?

Comment: if understand this properly the controller won't see any changes as it would be initialized each time route changes and you won't need a watch. Just need to set the scope variable from service

Comment: @ charlietfl : How do I determine whether it is update or create?

Comment: not quite clear which value determines that but isn't it `ShareProductService.getProduct()`? Another way would be with a url param. Am I understanding correct that route changes each time so the same condition doesn't exist in controller. Still a little confusing following the rout changes

Comment: My understanding is that once a product is set by Search controller, ShareProductService.getProductCode will continue returning that product. The route is the same '/createProduct'. SearchController does  $state.go('createProduct'). The route corresponding to createProduct state is /createProduct.

Comment: and you need edit ability right after create ...can toggle that in callback of create ajax